# Tracking position on Scroll in Angular2 not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, typescript, angular

I did create a directive to pin or unpin an header. Here is the HostListener on scroll. It works very well in Chrome/Firefox and Edge. However on IE11, everytime I do scroll, the function is called something like 5 times, thus breaking my logic. Anything I could do to prevent that from happening ?

```
   @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
    doSomething(event) {
      let topOffset = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop

      if(topOffset > this.scrollPosition) {
        this.el.classList.remove("pinned")
        this.el.classList.add("unpinned")
      }
      else {
        this.el.classList.remove("unpinned")
        this.el.classList.add("pinned")
      }
      this.scrollPosition = topOffset
    }
```

I am using Angular2 Beta-17 with : `es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js` and `es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js`

Edit: Is it normal and would the solution be simply using a debounce pattern ?

Comment: Tried both in Chrome and IE11 and it worked in the same correct way. I can assume the reason is not Angular but the `pinned`/`unpinned` class definitions. Probably they change the layout somehow and as a result change the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` value. Did you try to remove logic which adds/removes the classes and just log something into console instead?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: You can try not considering the case where topOffset === this.scrollPosition. It did fix the problem (so add an if topOffset<this.scrollPosition in the else)